# Can the same digital certificate be used by two different servers to connect as the same Connected App at the same time?

Tags: oauth, connected-apps

This is not a production scenario but I have a single Org with a single Connected App specified and connections to it are made using the JWT OAuth flow. The private key is used by two different test servers to access the Connected App. Can multiple connections be made or will the Connected App only allow one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple connections are totally allowed.